# Swift - WebView & Login Pop-ups

Tags: swift, safari, uiwebview, popup

First of all, thank you for making this site so awesome. (**ThumbsUp**) After reading lots, this is my first time asking a question.

I am trying to call a website from my UIWebView. Its calling websites such as Google and Yahoo like a charm. However, when trying to access the actually needed website, it doesn't provide me with a login-Popup. Calling the website via Safari does show the popup and after successful login the info I need to obtain.

```
import UIKit

class WebViewAssets: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webViewAssets: UIWebView!

@IBAction func backWebViewAssetsButton() {
    let presentingViewController: UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Asset"

    let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.websiteGoesHere.com")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webViewAssets.loadRequest(requestObj)
   }
}
```

[image: Login-Popup]

How do I enable my WebView to show the popup and let me login?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards
Peanutsmasher

Comment: Hi, I'm not sur to understand your needs. You got a UIWebView. You got on this web what you want if you hardcode "google.com" or "yahoo.com". Right ?

But what's wrong when you try with the desire website ???

Comment: Hi, the issue was, that the UIWebView would not show the initial Login PopUp and therefore not letting me access the link hardcoded in the code. (please see the attachment for the PopUp). However, issue is solved, as I implemented an SFSafariViewController instead. Such a nice tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent the issue by replacing the UIWebView with an SFSafariViewController. I highly recommend anyone to try the SFSafariViewController instead of the UIWebView as it brings all of Safari's functionality into your own app. Just search Google, awesome guides on how to use are available!

Best regards
Peanutsmasher